# How to convert RGBTRIPLE values into integers in C

Tags: c

In order to develop a filter program, I have to implement functionality that takes RGBTRIPLE values as integers, modifies them, and re-passes those values as RGBTRIPLEs. Specifically, typedef struct RGBTRIPLE is defined in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230309.aspx as

```
typedef struct tagRGBTRIPLE { 
  BYTE rgbtBlue; 
  BYTE rgbtGreen; 
  BYTE rgbtRed; 
} RGBTRIPLE;
```

What I cannot figure out is how to convert these intensities of the three different colors into integers so that I can manipulate them. I tried doing things like

```
RGBTRIPLE tmpimage[3][3];
int blue = tmpimage[0][0].rgbtBlue;
```

where each pixel of the image was already assigned values read from the actual bitmap.

However, whenever I run the program, it occurs that the .rgbtColor to integer conversion is not working. I figured this out by trying to print an integer variable after assigning to it the .rgbtColor value from a RGBTRIPLE data type variable. Instead of printing one number, it printed a long list of arbitrary numbers. I would appreciate to learn a way that allows me to convert such rgbtColor values into integers.

Comment: int blue = tmpimage[0][0].rgbtBlue is fine. The conclusion is that values aren't being assigned to the struct like they should. Or maybe RGBTRIPLE was defined as pointers somewhere and blue is retrieving pointer data instead of values. Step thru on a debugger or share the code used to define the array and assign values to the struct members.

Comment: Note that the values are automatically promoted to `int` during computation before being assigned to the smaller type. So for example `(255 * 3) / 4` will not overflow due to the intermediate value being larger than `BYTE`.

Comment: @weadhervane I do not see such a formula in the question. this question requires actual code,  clarity etc etc.

Comment: show the actual code which does not work. your question at this moment cannot be answered and should be closed

Answer (score -1):

int blue=tmpimage[0][0].rgbtBlue is enough..
RGBTRIPLE is defined as pointer somewhere and retrieving pointer data instead of values .